# How do I grab the Kohana Jelly Timestamp pretty_format

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, jelly

I was wondering if anyone with some Jelly experience would happen know how one would go about grabbing the pretty_format version of a Timestamp out of a Jelly_Field_Timestamp?

I wouldn't mind doing date($pretty_format, $value) as long as I could somehow get that $pretty_format value as I'm looping through my records.

```
$tasks = Jelly::select('task')->execute();
foreach ($tasks as $task)
{
    $task->time;
    #??? $task->time->pretty_format;
    #??? date($pretty_format, $task->time)
}
```

Something like this has to be possible... is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iirc, this is one way to do it:

```
$time_prettyformat = Jelly::builder('task')->fields('time')->pretty_format;
```

Another would be:

```
$task->meta()->fields('time')->pretty_format;
```

Note, this method only works in 0.9.x versions of Jelly.

Comment: Thank you. Though the first one gives me a fatal error while calling a protected method, the second one works like a charm. With one slight modification, $tasks => $task hence  $task->meta()->fields('time')->pretty_format; but I think it was my fault for presenting the problem badly like that in the first place. It all ends up looking like, date($task->meta()->fields('time')->pretty_format, $task->time) if there's a better way I'd love to know but this works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I'll edit my post to make it $task in the second sample. I'll check why the first doesn't work. Iirc, something similar should work. As for a 'better' way, I would store the pretty_format in a variable instead of fetching it through the ->meta() each loop.